# How to hide a value in a textbox?

Tags: jquery, html

I am showing the value in the textbox.The value comes from the database first I'm storing it in the variable.I have three radio buttons and when the **user click third radio button** the textbox will be disabled.**At that time I want to hide the textbox value displayed within the textbox.**But not to set it NULL.How can I do **Using Jquery**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hidden field to store the value that you create on the fly:

```
$("#thirdRadioId").click(function(){
    $("#textInputId").after('<input type="hidden" value="' + $("#textInputId").val() + '" />').val("").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

You would have to build some functionality to undo this if the user then selects a different radio button.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(#my_id).click(function(){
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#amount").val("");
    }else {
        $("#amount").val(YOUR_OWN_VALUE)
    }

}
```

So simple and easy. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you save current value attribute to a variable and then set input.value property to empty string ?

Comment: Becausewhen the user click the previous radio button it displays that stored value in that textbox.

Answer (score 0):

How about 1. disabling it the normal way (.disabled = true) and then giving the textbox a "transparent" text color?